# Opengl Screen to Map coord conversion

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a height map made of `glVertex3f` and need a way that I can dynamically change the height at certain points using the mouse, much the same way that a game like Simcity does when creating terrain like [this youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQMCze2GOfw).

This is my height map loop to create the terrain

```
for(float x = 0.0; x < MAP_WIDTH; x += d)
{
    for(float z = 0.0; z < MAP_HEIGHT; z += d)
    {
        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.f);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);   

            Color(HeightMap[(int)x][(int)z]);
            glVertex3f( x, HeightMap[(int)x][(int)z], -z);

            Color(HeightMap[(int)x+d][(int)z]);
            glVertex3f( x+d, HeightMap[(int)x+d][(int)z], -z);

            Color(HeightMap[(int)x+d][(int)z+d]);
            glVertex3f( x+d, HeightMap[(int)x+d][(int)z+d], -z+-d);

            Color(HeightMap[(int)x][(int)z+d]);
            glVertex3f( x, HeightMap[(int)x][(int)z+d], -z+-d);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

As you can see the height map gets its 'height' data from a 2d array. So when clicking on the map with the mouse the correct element within the 2d array needs to be changed.

I use `gluLookAt` in my Camera class if that makes any difference.

- What is the best way to go about this?
- How can I convert screen coords to map coords?

side note: I hear that `glBegin / glEnd` is deprecated, what would I use instead or do I not need it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to look into Vertex Array Objects (VAO) to replace glBegin/glEnd.

Despite that, I think you could still make it work with what you have there first, then worry about using the most efficient API usage later.

What you need is [gluUnproject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml) which takes your mouse's screen coordinate, the terrain's model, view, and projection matrices and returns the mouse cursor in object space.

 You can then perform a ray-cast onto the terrain and elevate the vertices that the ray intersects with.